# why we use document.form[0] other than document.form[1(or)2...] in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

why we use 0 in document.form[0].if i use 1 insteadof 0 it will not work anybody please explain that.
my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function preferedBrowser() {
//here if i use document.forms[1] it will not work
prefer = document.forms[0].browsers.value;
alert("You prefer browsing internet with " + prefer);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
Choose which browser you prefer:
<select id="browsers" onchange="preferedBrowser()">
<option>Chrome</option>
<option >Internet Explorer</option>
<option>Firefox</option>
</select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*document.forms* returns the collection of all the forms of a document. So as its returning a collection you need to address specific form using it's index. There are other ways also to get specific form i.e. using *id* attribute

```
<form id="myForm"></form>

var aForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
```

In your case it's a single form so you have to address that using 0 index. But in many web pages developers need multiple forms. So there you might need to use the correct index.

Still its preferable to call a specific form with it's id attribute. Who wants to call something with a number rather a name. As id is to be unique for each element so you will get lots of benefit out of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have only 1 `<form>` object in your html page.
The array is zero based.

Answer (score 1):

`document.form` is an array of the form elements in the document's body, and array start with index of 0, and since you only have 1 form the `document.form` array has only 1 element in it witch it's index is 0

Answer (score 1):

In a HTML page with multiple form

You access the first form by index 0 i,e document.forms[0];

and the second one by index 1 and so on.

[For example follow this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_forms3)

Answer (score 0):

Array's in Javascript start from index "0" not from "1". So, if you have only one form you can access it from "0th" index. if you have two forms you can access the second form using document.form[1] ....and so on...

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms`, plural form. It's an array-like data structure (HTMLCollection actually), and is zero-based.